# SQL Server Select statement grouping of records

Tags: sql-server, select, grouping

I have a "Chat" application in which we have a groups of chat between users. So one user can be a part of multiple groups.

Once user login we have to show all the groups of user and their messages.

But we have a bucket/limit of 100 messages at the time of login for each group messages. Means we will show only 100 messages(latest messages) to user for each group and to show rest of the messages there is a button "Load earlier messages".

But this limit of 100 messages may change on the basis of below scenarios-

1. We have to show only 100 messages (as per the bucket size) if all the messages are Read for each group.
2. We have to show all UnRead messages for each group, there is no bucket for Unread messages.
3. And the last scenario is the some of Read  &  UnRead messages.

   - If there are >= 100 Unread messages and some Read messages then we will only show all UnRead messages. Because it(UnRead messages) exceed the bucket size and we cant show the Read messages here.
   - If there are 50 UnRead messages and 50 Read messages then we can show all     the messages because it's not exceeding the bucket size.
   - If there are 60 UnRead and 50 Read messages then we have to show total 100 messages in which 60 messages will be UnRead and 40 will be Read messages.

So as per the above scenarios we have to show all the UnRead messages in all scenarios whether it's exceeding the bucket size or not.

Below are the tables that we are using -

**(1)** `Group` table:

```
   GroupId(PK)            GroupName
    g1                      Group_A
    g2                      Group_B
    g3                      Group_C
    g4                      Group_D
    g5                      Group_E
```

**(2)** `ChatMessage` (`GroupId` is FKey here)

```
  ChatMessageId(PK)  GroupId(FK)  Message   CreatedDate
  m1                   g1          hi       25 Jan, 2017
  m2                   g2          hi1      26 Jan, 2017
  m3                   g1          hi2      25 Jan, 2017
  m4                   g1          hi3      25 Jan, 2017  
  m5                   g3          hi4      27 Jan, 2017
  m6                   g4          hi5      28 Jan, 2017
  m7                   g5          hi6      29 Jan, 2017
  m8                   g2          hi7      26 Jan, 2017
  m9                   g3          hi8      27 Jan, 2017
  m10                  g4          hi9      30 Jan, 2017
```

**(3)** `ChatMessageMember` (ChatMessageId and GroupId's are FKey's here)

```
 MemberId  ChatMessageId  GroupId   UserId  ISMessageRead   CreatedDate
 cm1                m1       g1     111      Yes            25 Jan, 2017
 cm2                m1       g1     222      Yes            25 Jan, 2017
 cm3                m2       g2     111      No             26 Jan, 2017
 cm4                m2       g2     222      Yes            26 Jan, 2017
 cm5                m3       g1     111      No             25 Jan, 2017
 cm6                m3       g1     222      Yes            25 Jan, 2017
 cm7                m4       g1     111      No             25 Jan, 2017
 cm8                m4       g1     222      Yes            25 Jan, 2017
 cm9                m5       g3     111      Yes            27 Jan, 2017
 cm10               m5       g3     222      Yes            27 Jan, 2017
 cm11               m6       g4     111      No             25 Jan, 2017
 cm12               m6       g4     222      No             25 Jan, 2017
 cm13               m7       g5     111      No             29 Jan, 2017
 cm14               m7       g5     222      No             29 Jan, 2017
 cm15               m8       g2     111      Yes            26 Jan, 2017
 cm16               m8       g2     222      Yes            26 Jan, 2017
 cm17               m9       g3     111      Yes            27 Jan, 2017
 cm18               m9       g3     222      Yes            27 Jan, 2017
 cm19               m10      g4     111      Yes            30 Jan, 2017
 cm20               m10      g4     222      Yes            30 Jan, 2017
```

We are using below criteria to get the records -

```
select cmm.* 
from ChatMessageMember cmm
where UserId =  111 and CreatedDate <= '31 Jan, 2017'
```

So according to above query records should be based on the "UserId" and the given "Date". Here we are using CreatedDate as a endTime means we have to pick records till that DateTime. But for Starting point we have two cases-

1. Let's start from endtime so starting point would be the 100th record but if the 100th record is "UnRead" then we have to pick records till the last "UnRead" record in a sequence (until we did not get any "Read" record).
2. But if we find any "Read" record at 100th position then it will be our starting point.

Can anybody help me out in this complex scenario where I have to take care of query performance as well.

FYI, I am using SQL Server 2012 and VS 2015.

**Update :**
For the output please check below scenario-

```
please check the below table. For ex the bucket/limit is 3 and CreatedDate
is  "30 Jan, 2017". So according to limit and Date filter the messages  
should be m7,m6 & m5 for group 1 (g1). But there is an "UnRead" messages  
ahead after 3 messages (at position m4 & m2). So we have to pick records 
till last "UnRead" message from CreatedDate. Means from m7 to m2. So 
messages will be (m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7).


Message             IsMessageRead          GroupId         CreatedDate
 m1                    yes                   g1            26 Jan, 2017
 m2                    no                    g1            27 Jan, 2017
 m3                    yes                   g1            27 Jan, 2017
 m4                    no                    g1            27 Jan, 2017
 m5                    no                    g1            27 Jan, 2017
 m6                    yes                   g1            27 Jan, 2017
 m7                    no                    g1            28 Jan, 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    messages (row_number, memberid, chatmessageid, groupid, userid, ismessageread, createddate) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ismessageread ASC) rn
            , memberid
            , chatmessageid
            , groupid
            , userid
            , ismessageread
            , createddate 
        FROM
            ChatMessageMember cmm
        WHERE 
            UserId =  111 
            AND CreatedDate <= '31 Jan, 2017'
    ),
    messages_summary (num_unread) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(CASE WHEN ismessageread = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) num_unread
        FROM 
            messages
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    rn <= (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN num_unread > 100 THEN num_unread ELSE 100 END num_messages_to_return 
        FROM 
            messages_summary
    )
```

Comment: I have updated my question. There is one case here if we find any "UnRead" record at 100th position then we have to pick record till we did not get any "Read" record. It means the total records may be greater than 100.

Comment: Try changing the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE rn <= 100 OR ismessageread = 'No'`

Comment: @boss how does this answer not provide what is being sought? it returns data that meets the conditions you specified...

Comment: He only wants the first 100 records _unless_ there are more than 100 unread messages, then he wants all unread.

Comment: The query does this

Comment: No, it will always return only the first 100 rows.

Comment: @MichaelL. The _row_numer()_ window function enumerates all the rows, starting with the _ismessageread = no_ first due to _order by asc_. This gives the results OP was looking for when the predicate _rn <= 100_ is executed

Comment: @user1327961 I understand that it will show unread messages first, but it will never return _more_ than 100 rows. If there are 500 unread messages, the OP wants all of them.

Comment: @Michael L , yes you are correct. Also we have use row_number() OVER (order by groupid asc) rn, because messages are based on groups. Please confirm.

Comment: @Boss Should you be ordering by groupid or should you be restricting groupid in the where clause?

Comment: @Boss updated to meet needs of > 100 num unread messages, return all unread otherwise return only 100 with mix of all unread and the difference being read

Comment: @Michael L, I am adding inner join of "GroupId" and to get rownumber() count I am using below query-

ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by groupId order by CreatedDate desc) rn

Comment: @Michael L, your query is working fine -

WHERE
 rn <= 100 OR (IsMessageRead = 'No')

but there is only one issue with this query is that it's not picking the "Read" message after 100 RowCount. Because it's checking for Unread Messages only after 100 but I want all the messages after 100 till the last UnRead message.

Comment: @Boss does my adjusted answer give you what you want?

Comment: @user1327961, there is a same issue with your updated query as well that I mentioned for Michael in my above comment.

Comment: @Boss Still unclear, sounds like changing requirements? Your original question stated "If there are >= 100 Unread messages and some Read messages then we will only show all UnRead messages. Because it(UnRead messages) exceed the bucket size and we cant show the Read messages here."... If unread < 100, give all unread and (100 - num_unread) read messages as the difference.  If unread >= 100, then get all unread messages... this is the requirement as per your original post....

Comment: @user1327961, please check my updated question for the output that I need.